# what is mean by dict

Tags: c++, vector

I came through a program which was like below

```
firstMissingPositive(vector<int> &A) {
    vector<bool> dict(A.size()+1,false);

    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
            if(A[i]>0 && A[i]<dict.size()) dict[A[i]]=true;
    }

    if(A.size()==1 && A[0]!=1) return 1;
    else if(A.size()==1 && A[0]==1) return 2;

    int i=0;
    for(i=1;i<dict.size();i++){
        if(dict[i]==false) return i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

In this program, I could not get what is mean by following line

```
          vector<bool> dict(A.size()+1,false);
```

What is dict and  this statement?

Comment: `dict` is a vector of `bool` type with all its elements having value as `false`

Comment: Do you know the concepts of templates? I guess that has the most potential for confusing you.

Comment: You might be interested in our list of [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a variable.

The definition of the variable calls a specific constructor of the vector to initialize it with a specific size, and initialize all elements to a specific value.

It's equivalent to

```
vector<bool> dict;
dict.resize(A.size()+1,false);
```

See e.g. [this `std::vector` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for more information about available constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring container of `bool`'s (it means variables which stores only `0`/`1` (`8B`)) which has same count of elements as `int` vector `A` and all these elements are set to `false` -> `0`.

It calls this constructor

```
 vector (size_type n, const value_type& val,
       const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

**Example**:

This is `vector` `A`:

```
  0   1   2   3   4    <- Indexes
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |     (int)
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Its size is 5, so it would declare container with size 5, initialized to `0`'s.

```
  0   1   2   3   4    <- Indexes
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |     (bool)
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

---

In this case its used to flag indexes in first `vectror`.

For example it is often used for [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). You can set `1`'s to primes with each iteration. It would be (for numbers `0-4`)

```
  0   1   2   3   4
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Then you know on which indexes are primes in `vector` `A`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
{
    if ( dict[i] == true )
    {
        std::cout << "Prime number: << A[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an definition of a variable "dict" of type vector. And please Google it first